# Echo server/client message cutoff using socket send()/recv()(winsock)

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming

The code for echo_server and echo_client is posted below. I noticed that when I type a message over a certain length in the echo_client, the server truncates the end of it and echoes back only part of it. The buffer size is 1024 bytes and the message I'm typing is much, much shorter than that length. What's going on here? How do I solve this problem so the server echoes back the complete message provided its under the length limit?

The server code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>


#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;


static int MAXPENDING = 5;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{

WSADATA wsaData;
int iResult;
int optv = 0;
bool connected = false;
char *optval = (char*)&optv;
int optlen = sizeof(optval);
string Q = "quit";
const char *exit =Q.c_str();




iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
    wprintf(L"WSAStartup function failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
    return 1;
}


if(argc!=2){
    printf("Error: incorrect number of arguments.  ");
    return 1;
}


SOCKET servSock;
servSock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
if(servSock==INVALID_SOCKET){
    printf("Socket function failed with error: %d\n",GetLastError());
    return 1;
}


u_int servPort = atoi(argv[1]);

sockaddr_in servAddr;
servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
servAddr.sin_port = htons(servPort);

int opt = setsockopt(servSock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,optval,sizeof(optval));


if(bind(servSock,(sockaddr*)&servAddr,sizeof(servAddr))<0){
    printf("Bind function failed with error: %d\n", GetLastError());
    return 1;
}



for(;;){


    if(listen(servSock,MAXPENDING) < 0){
    printf("Listen function failed with error: %d/n",GetLastError());
    return 1;
    }else{
        char *str = new char[5];

        printf("Server listening on port %d\n",servPort);
    }

    SOCKET clientSock;
    sockaddr_in clientAddr;
    socklen_t caddrlen = sizeof(clientAddr);



    clientSock = accept(servSock,(sockaddr*)&clientAddr,&caddrlen);

    if(clientSock < 0){
       printf("Accept() function failed with error: %d/n", GetLastError());
       goto QUIT;

    }else if(clientSock >=0){
        connected = true;
    }



    char cName[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];

    if(inet_ntop(AF_INET,&clientAddr.sin_addr,cName,sizeof(cName))!=NULL){
        printf("Handling client %s/%d\n", cName,ntohs(clientAddr.sin_port));
    }else{
        printf("Error: Unable to get client address");
    }


    char buffer[1024];


    while(connected==true){



        long nbytesrcvd = recv(clientSock,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);




        if(nbytesrcvd==0){
            connected = false;
            cout << endl;
            cout << cName << ": client disconnected" << endl;                   
            cout << endl;
            break;
        }



        if(nbytesrcvd < 0){
            printf("Error: recv() failed");
            cout << endl;
            goto QUIT;
        }


         if(nbytesrcvd > 0){

            long nbytessent = send(clientSock,buffer,nbytesrcvd,0);
            if(nbytessent < 0){
                cout << "Error: send() failed" << endl;
                cout << endl;
                goto QUIT;          

            }else if(nbytessent!=nbytesrcvd){
                cout << "send() error: sent unexpected # of bytes" << endl;
                cout << endl;
                goto QUIT;

            }                       
         }

    }



    QUIT:

        int iResult = closesocket(clientSock);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("closesocket function failed with error: %d\n",GetLastError());
        }



    }




}
```

And the client code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>


#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <Windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>


#define BUFFSIZE 1024

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;


int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{


WSADATA wsaData;
int result;
bool connected = false;
hostent *rhost;
char buffer[BUFFSIZE];
string Q = "quit";
const char *exit =Q.c_str();






result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
if (result != NO_ERROR) {
    printf("WSAStartup function failed with error: %d\n", result);
    return 1;
}




SOCKET connector;
connector = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
if (connector == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    wprintf(L"socket function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

string hname;
cout << "Enter host name(URL): ";
cin >> hname;
cout << endl;

string portnum;
cout << "Enter the port number you wish to connect on: " ;
cin >> portnum;
cout << endl;

char *hostname = const_cast<char*>(hname.c_str());
char *hostPort = const_cast<char*>(portnum.c_str());



rhost = gethostbyname(hostname);
in_addr addr;
addr.s_addr = *(u_long *)rhost->h_addr_list[0];



sockaddr_in clientserv;
clientserv.sin_family = AF_INET;
clientserv.sin_addr.s_addr = addr.s_addr;
clientserv.sin_port = htons(atoi(hostPort));

if(connect(connector,(sockaddr*)&clientserv,sizeof(clientserv))==SOCKET_ERROR){
    printf("connect function failed with error: %d\n", GetLastError());
    if(closesocket(connector)<0){
        printf("closesocket function failed %d\n", GetLastError());
    }
    return 1;
}else{
    connected = true;
    cout << "Connected to host " << hname << " on port " << portnum << endl;
    cout << "Type 'quit' to exit the program " << endl;
}


while(connected==true){

   int nbr = 0;
   string msg;

   cout << ">";
   getline(cin,msg);
   cout << endl;




   if(msg=="quit"){

       connected = false;
       goto quit;
   }


   int len = sizeof(msg);
   const char *message = msg.c_str();
   strncpy_s(buffer,message,sizeof(msg));         
   long nbs = send(connector,buffer,len,0);
   if(nbs < 0){
        printf("send() failed", GetLastError());
        return 1;
   }

   while(nbr < nbs){
        nbr = recv(connector,buffer,len,0);
        if(nbr < 0){
            printf("recv() failed", GetLastError());
            return 1;

        }else if(nbr==0){
            printf("recv() failed: connection closed prematurely", GetLastError());
            return 1;               
        }else if(nbr > 0){
            string str(buffer);
            cout << ">> " << str << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }

   }



}

quit:

    if (closesocket(connector) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("closesocket function failed with error: %ld\n", GetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }


WSACleanup();

return 0;
```

}

Comment: In the client, don't do the `const_cast` of the strings returned by the `c_str` function. The functions you use have their arguments being `const char *` and so should you.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `recv` may not receive all of the data at once. This means that the `recv` call in the server may not get the complete message, but send back what it gets and in turn the client may receive only a part of what is sent from the server.

This would not be a problem, unless you only receive *once* in the client and then continue doing something else. Just like you do.

There are two solutions to this:

1. Make a simple protocol that either prepends each message with the message length, or have a special end-of-message marker. In the first case you will always know how much data there is and can read in a loop until all is received, in the second case you receive in aloop until you get the end-of-message marker.
2. Make the sockets non-blocking, and read in a loop until `recv` returns an error with the error being `WSAEWOULDBLOCK`. Then there is no more data to read.

---

Mistakes in the client:

```
int len = sizeof(msg);
```

This line returns the size of the string *object*, not the string contained inside the object. You should use `msg.length()` to get the length. You use this in a couple of places.

Using a `std::string` is quite okay, if you use it properly. E.g.:

```
long nbs = send(connector, msg.c_str(), msg.length(), 0);
```

Another thing:

```
nbr = recv(connector, buffer, len, 0);
```

You again use the wrong size here, the one provided by the previously and erroneously use of `sizeof(msg)`. Instead you should provide the size of the actual buffer. Since `buffer` is a proper array you can use e.g. `sizeof(buffer) - 1` here. The `-1` is because the data you send from the client is not an zero-terminated string, and so you need to reserve a space in the received data to terminate it like a string:

```
buffer[nbr] = '\0';
```

Comment: These issues do not really apply in a simple echo system like the OP's code, but they are valid points in more complex systems.

Comment: Joachim Pileborg, thanks for your advice but that is actually unnecessary. TCP allows you to prepend messages of arbitrary length using the setsockopt() function and the SO_RCVBUFF/SO_SENDBUFF options. But what worked is taking the client console input as a char array instead of a string.

Comment: @MrX Re-read the client code, and added a few points about it.

Answer (score 0):

I see several problems with your code.

Your server is calling `listen()` inside the `accept()` loop.  It does not belong here.  Call `listen()` only once, after `bind()`.

`send()` can accept fewer bytes than requested.  When sending a buffer, call `send()` in a loop until the entire buffer is exhausted.  Your client and server code both suffer from this.

Your client code is copying the user's input into a buffer and then sending the entire buffer, even if the input is smaller than the buffer.  That will also truncate the input if it is larger than the buffer.  In both cases,you don't need that buffer at all.  You can pass the input string directly to `send()`, using the string's `c_str()` and `length()` methods.  That way, the entire string gets sent regardless of its actual length.

Your client code is also not taking the return value of `recv()` into account when converting the echoed data into a `string`.  The data is not null terminated, so you need to pass the `nbr` variable as the second parameter of the `string` constructor.

Comment: Remy, I actually solved this problem by reading console input from the client program as a char array instead of a string.

Comment: I used:  scanf("%s",buffer) instead of getline(cin,msg). The reason for the listen() function being nested inside of the for(;;) loop is so that the server will continue to listen for incoming client connections as long as the server program is running.

Comment: Using `scanf()` like that has potential for a buffer overflow. You need to tell it the size of your buffer so it won't overflow. And you DO NOT need to call `listen()` in a loop. Once the server starts listening, it stays listening until it is closed. You only need to call `accept()` in a loop.